# How to read Abaqus .mtx file? Scipy.io.mmread gives 'not enough values to unpack' error

Tags: python, io, scipy

I'd like to read a .mtx file using Python. The .mtx file is generated by Abaqus and looks like this:

```
1,1, 1,1,  1.939258533333333e-02
1,2, 1,2,  1.939258533333333e-02
2,1, 2,1,  1.889629366666666e-02
```

It seems that scipy.io.mmread would work, but when I ran the following code:

```
import scipy.io

with open(abs_file_path) as mass_file:
    otpt = scipy.io.mmread(mass_file)
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_read_mass_mtx.py", line 12, in <module>
    read_mass(file_path)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Temp/python/data_functions/read_mass_mtx.py", line 6, in read_mass
    otpt = scipy.io.mmread(mass_file)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/mmio.py", line 76, in mmread
    return MMFile().read(source)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/mmio.py", line 414, in read
    self._parse_header(stream)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/mmio.py", line 478, in _parse_header
    self.__class__.info(stream)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/mmio.py", line 232, in info
    [asstr(part.strip()) for part in line.split()]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaqus and SciPy don't agree on what a Matrix Market file should look like.

The first issue which causes your error is that SciPy expects whitespace between every column, hence your "expected 5, got 3" error. Changing your example input manually to contain whitespace:

```
1, 1, 1, 1,  1.939258533333333e-02
1, 2, 1, 2,  1.939258533333333e-02
2, 1, 2, 1,  1.889629366666666e-02
```

The error changes to

```
ValueError: source is not in Matrix Market format
```

This makes sense to me, because [the docs of `mmread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmread.html) says the return value is

> Dense or sparse matrix depending on the matrix format in the Matrix Market file.

Which might mean that there's at least some metadata (headers?) missing from the file, making it non-standard. So either

1. the file is not a proper .mtx file, or
2. the given format is not supported by SciPy

Either way you'll probably have to parse the file yourself. If you know what the first four columns mean you can probably easily parse it using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

scipy is following the formats from the NIST matrix market
https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/

When dumping matrices from Abaqus you have to include `Format=Coordinate` on `*MATRIX OUTPUT` Its probably also a good idea to look at other options for `*MATRIX GENERATE` like `ELSET=FOO` to control your matrices data.

that will get you a 3 column file, defining a sparse matrix with the columns:

```
i j A(i,j)
```

after that you have to take the addition step of prepending some information to the file

The first line defines the type of nist mtx file it is

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
```

There are other options for complex valued matrices and symmetric matrices documented at NIST.

The second line to prepend defines the matrix size

```
    nrows ncols #ofentries
```

`#ofentries` is the original number of lines in the file abaqus produced. `nrows` and `ncols` are both probably the # of nodes in your model times the # of active degrees of freedom, however MPCs and other things can alter this.

So if you had 4x4 matrix with 2 non-zero entries like this

```
0  0  0  0
0 45  0  0
0  0 74  0
0  0  0  0
```

the file would come out of abaqus as

```
2 2 45
3 3 74
```

and your edited mtx file would look like

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
4 4 2
2 2 45
3 3 74
```

Finally scipy imports it as a sparse matrix so you may need to utilize scipy.sparse.linalg to do anything with it